# Webdriver: to click on Onclick

Tags: onclick, webdriver

Help me to click.

```
    <div class="items">
<ul>
<li class="first">
<a onclick="launch("mary", "mario", "1"); return false;" href="/">Cash</a>
</li>
<li class="last">
<a onclick="launch("mary", "mario", "2"); return false;" href="/">Credit</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And I wrote code as which is a syntax error and NOTE: i cant take by xpath position or with text contains, because position is not constant it shuffles and cant write as text contains "cash/credit" because in a page many games are present with same text.

```
d1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='nucleus_launch_game("slots","brittonaire", "1"); return false;']"));
```

Comment: try to use with xpath as: d1.findElement(By.xpath(//a[contains(@onclick,"\"mary\",\"mario\",\"1\"")]))

Comment: Its not working buddy showing error as he method "xpath(String) in the type By is not applicable for the arguments (void)"

Comment: oh my mistake - put that in quotes as `"//a[contains(@onclick,'\"mary\",\"mario\",\"1\"')]"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

d1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Cash')]"));  -- To click on Cash URL
d1.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Credit')]"));  -- To click on Credit URL

Comment: I cant use contains.. because page has many text with cash and credit

Comment: No issues
Can you please post a big snippet of html, This will help me a lot to figure out other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below locaor:

d1.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='first']/a[text()='Cash']"));
d1.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='last']/a[text()='Credit']"));

If still doesn't work and it has duplicate elements with text, replace

`/a[text()='Cash']` with

```
/a[text()='Cash' and @onClick='\"mary\",\"mario\",\"1\"']
```

It will work

Comment: I directly used sikuli.. Thank you so much guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help... I sorted it off integrating it with other tool